# Adding Multiple Markers To Google Map on iPhone app

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am writing an iPhone application that uses google maps SDK to display a city. I need to add multiple markers on the map to identify certain locations.

I could loop through and add each marker upon the map load, but I don't believe this is a efficient technique(it seems very unnecessarily and resource heavy!!)?

Or is there some "Lazy loading" technique I could use to pull in the markers that are currently in view?

Answer (score 0):

For that you can add it in map region wise, you have to add marker only for current displaying  map region, but for this also you need to run loop.

So you can avoid other markers that would added to map.